# JHipster - Active profile ignored (not set) when @SpringBootTest is run

Tags: spring-boot, config, jhipster

It appears that active profile is ignored when running @SpringBootTest in JHipster generated application.

When I run application I can see the correct active profiles set.

```
.. The following profiles are active: swagger,dev
```

When I run @SpringBootTest I see the following:

```
... No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
```

JHipster stores config files under `src/main/resources/config`. If I move them one level up to `src/main/resources` as in standard spring-boot application the @SpringBootTest picks up the active profiles properly, however it breaks other things.

Any ideas on how to set active profile in JHipster application for integration tests?

Thanks.

Comment: JHipster runs tests in the default profile.  They should not depend on the `dev` or `prod` profiles, is there a reason you need this?

Comment: @Jon Ruddell I have some long running integration tests that I'd like to run only under specific profile. Is there a reason JHipster stepped away from default spring-boot behavior?

Comment: There is a test application.yml you can alter in `src/test/resources/config` that is loaded for the tests.  The default Spring Boot behavior is to test with the `default` profile (based on a Spring Initializr app)

Comment: Interesting. That's not the behavior I'm seeing. The tests run under whatever active profile is set in the application.yml. Completely missed the application.yml under src/test/resources/config. I'll see if I can make it work using test application.yml. Thanks.